# how is my ansible condtional broken? Why are both debug statements working?

Tags: if-statement, yaml, ansible

**I want**

The "password generation" step to only run IF the {{ mysql.password }} var does not equal "random"

The "debug password generation"  step to only run IF the password generation was run.

The "debug password being set" step to only run if the password generation step was skipped

**What is happening**

All steps are run

**My files**

playbook.yml

```
# tasks file for git_deployment
- name: Generate DB login_password
  shell: mkpasswd.pl --length=32
  args:
    creates: /tmp/.dbpwd
  register: dbpwd
  when: mysql.password != "random"

- name: debug password genreation
  debug: var=dbpwd
  when: dbpwd is defined
- name: debug password being set
  debug: var=mysql
  when: { mysql.password != "random" }

- name: create database
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ mysql.db }}"
    state: present
```

emphasized textrole-tasks.yml

```
# tasks file for git_deployment
- name: Generate DB login_password
  shell: mkpasswd.pl --length=32
  args:
    creates: /tmp/.dbpwd
  register: dbpwd
  when: mysql.password != "random"

- name: debug password genreation
  debug: var=dbpwd
  when: dbpwd is defined
- name: debug password being set
  debug: var=mysql
  when: { mysql.password != "random" }

- name: create database
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ mysql.db }}"
    state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

By enclosing some of the conditional expressions in single braces, you're wrapping them in a dictionary, which coerces to `True`. Get rid of the single braces- `when:` expects a raw Jinja2 expression, not a template (which would be double braces anyway).